# Mongo db query all documents contains substring matching in a given array of strings

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose

The title might be a little confusing, here is the data:

location_collection:

```
{name: "A"}
{name: "A1"}
{name: "B"}
{name: "B1"}
{name: "C"}
{name: "C1"}
```

my query:

```
 mongooseModel.find({ name: { $in: ['A', 'B'] } })
```

what I get:

```
{name: "A"}
{name: "B"}
```

What I want to get:

```
{name: "A"}
{name: "A1"}
{name: "B"}
{name: "B1"}
```

I try this but it doesnt work:

```
 mongooseModel.find({ name: { $in: [$substr:['A'], $substr:['B']] } })
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $regex

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      name: {
        $regex: "A",
        
      }
    },
    {
      name: {
        $regex: "B",
        
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/BMV2oNDjp-1